# How to use REGEX to strip off all text after a number and include the number in a column

Tags: regex

My goal is to use REGEX to create two columns of data from a long text string containing some alpha text followed by numeric.   There are no delimeters in the data.

With the data example below I want the first column to be 'Test scores, Math' and the second column will be `'62 73 87 99'`   (in quotes as it's text data)

***Sample data***

`Test scores, Math 62 73 87 99`

I've used the REGEX below to strip off the alpha part of the string creating the first column
`\n(^[^123456789]*)`

Now, I want to create a second column with just the numbers

Comment: Regular expressions come in different flavors. Which one are you trying to use? Rather: What program are you using to apply the regex on the input?

Answer (score 0):

Due to the lack of other example columns, the behavior can have a bunch of edge cases, which you must decide how to handle. What, e.g. if there is a number in the text? does the first number define the start of the numeric sequence, and non-numeric characters are just dropped from the number string? Or does the text end with the last non-blank, non-numeric character?

Also: there are different regex flavors. Depending on the program you are using to decode the input string, you might require different instructions.
And: What exactly is a 'column' for you? I will assume you mean a comma separated file (CSV) as output, with ';' as delimiter.

If you want a 'simple' solution, an answer could be:
`^(.+[^\d])\s+(\d+)$` as regex, and `$1;$2` as replacement-string.

This would take each line in a file and split the numeric part from the text part with a ';', so you could then open it with excel, or any other CSV-viewer.

How this works:

```regex
^ "is the line start (in all flavors I know of)."
() "is a 'non-silent group' which means, that you can use the captured characters with `$1`, `$2`... in a replacement string."
.+ "means a positive number of anything non-line-break (unless you specify otherwise)."
[^\d] "means anything not numeric."
\s+ "means any positive (non-zero) number of whitespaces."
\d+ "is a positive (non-zero) number of digits."
$ "is usually the line terminator (this might depend on your flavor)."
```

Answer (score 0):

As TreffnonX comments, the regex engine (BRE, ERE, PCRE etc.) is not specified and we cannot find the best answer but the following will work with most platforms:

```
^([^0-9]*)([0-9 ]*)$
```

[Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/2vsI8Y/1)